# Why my code is not encrypting the password if i inherit django user?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Im learning about django, and i need create a customized user, called Person. I  use inherit from contrib.auth.models User, but in my django administrator the form for add a new Teacher dont show the field confirm password and the password is not encrypted in the table user

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager

# Create your models here.


class Person (User):

    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ClassRoom (models.Model):
    classroom = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=False, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.classroom


class Teacher(Person):
    phone = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=15, blank=False, null=False)
    classroom = models.ManyToManyField(ClassRoom)
```

You can see in this photo as the first and second users is saved encripting the password(this users was added as normal user in the django administrator), but the last(creadted as Teacher in the django administrator) dont encrypt the pass.

¿Someone can help me?
[database photo user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN9jU.png)

Comment: how are you setting the password?

Answer (score 4):

In order to encrypt a password, you need to set it through User's `set_password` method. for example,

```
user = User(
            email=email, is_staff=False, is_active=True,
            is_superuser=False,
            last_login=now, date_joined=now, **extra_fields)

user.set_password(password)
user.save(using=self._db)
```

Comment: But if my class Person inherit from User, why i have to doo this?

Comment: Because encryption is managed by the model method so when you pass password kwarg to Person model it doesn't convert the password to encrypted one. But when you call set_password method, what it do inside is, encrypt password first and then set the value to <instance>.password field (you can see by looking code detail). So later saved the encrypted password whereas former not. django admin create user by using User.objects.create_user(), which has similar implementation like the one mention in above answer.